# The phys_to_virt() function introduced delay in the bootup screen and hence the flickering in the image. How to remove this?

Tags: linux-kernel, framebuffer

In my bootloader, I am displaying some image while booting up the board. Now when the kern boot up starts, I take this addres and do

```
phys_to_virt(bootloaderfb);
```

Due to this I see a small flicker in the image and then target boots. How do I remove this flicker?

Comment: All `phys_to_virt` does is add a constant to the address. A single call is meaningless. If you're doing it per-pixel, you can try to optimize by remembering the physical address.

Comment: I am not doing it per-pixel. Infact I did it per-pixel and my this method, and could see a small difference. I want to completely remove this flicker. Any suggession. The whole concept here is to pass the frame buffer from bootloader to kernel so that kernel continue displaying same image until by android boots up.

Comment: I can't see the relation between `phys_to_virt` and the flicker. If the flicker is due to CPU wasted somewhere, it's very unlikely that `phys_to_virt` is the place.